# Brown/black spots on tomato plants - what can that be?

Tags: plant-care, diseases, tomatoes

We have tomato plants where some of the leaves (maybe 20-50%) have
brown spots. The spots look brown to me, but look more black in the photo.
I'll try to add an image. The leaves that don't have spots look healthy.

I don't think the spots are caused by magnesium deficiency since we are using
fertilizer with magnesium.
Do you have an idea of what could be the problem? Drought?

[image: tomato plant leaves with spots]